# Como usar Javascript com Bootstrap4?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, front-end, bootstrap-4

Estou fazendo meu front-end com Bootstrap, quero usar js para eventos como onclick, por exemplo.

[image: Meu código]

Caso não dê pra visualizar a imagem (versao resumida):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>AgileHub - Parafernalia</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="parafernalia.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body style="background-color: #F8F8FF">
     <div>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm col-12" id="new" onclick="AddNewCard()">New issue</button>
     </div>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    function AddNewCard(){
        alert('Teste');
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Já inseri o jQuery e o bootstrap.js, mas ainda assim não está funcionando. Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: Recomendo você ler aqui: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Bootstrap da versão 4 pra cima, requer "popper.js": jQuery primeiro, depois Popper.js, depois Bootstrap JS

Comment: Não esquece de colocar `<!doctype html>` na primeira linha.

Comment: Eu coloquei o doctype e os scripts na ordem, mas ainda não funcionou, não acontece nada quando clico o botão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue onde está o erro:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>AgileHub - Parafernalia</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="parafernalia.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body style="background-color: #F8F8FF">
     <div>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm col-12" id="new" onclick="AddNewCard()">New issue</button>
     </div>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.js"> <-- aqui está errado
    function AddNewCard(){
        alert('Teste');
    }

    </script>  <---- aqui está errado
</body>
</html>
```

Segue o código correto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AgileHub - Parafernalia</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="parafernalia.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>    
  <body style="background-color: #F8F8FF">
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm col-12" id="new" onclick="AddNewCard()">New issue</button>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">    <-------abre
      function AddNewCard(){ alert('Teste'); }  <------ código 
    </scripts> <------ fecha
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Agora foi, muito obrigada :)